How to stack datasets with a subsets columns?
Suppose I have two datasets:
df1 <- data.frame(
  x = c(1,2,3),
  y = c('a', 'b', 'c')
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  x = c(4,5,6)
)

I would like to stack or union these data as:
df12 = data.frame(
  x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
  y = c('a', 'b', 'c', NA, NA, NA)
)


OH well I just answered my own question:
merge(df1, df2, all=T)

produces the desired output.
> merge(df1, df2, all=T)
  x    y
1 1    a
2 2    b
3 3    c
4 4 <NA>
5 5 <NA>
6 6 <NA>


If you prefer a tidyverse approach
dplyr::bind_rows(df1,df2)

